# AngularFire miss field after set

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I try to refresh value field like. But title and body values update correctly.

```
$scope.refreshTime = function(){
    $scope.time = new Date();
};

$scope.changeMessage = function(key) {
    $scope.refreshTime();
    console.log($scope.time);
    var child = $scope.messages.$child(key);

    child.$set({title: $scope.title, body: $scope.msg, time: $scope.time});
}

$scope.addMessage = function(e) {
    $scope.refreshTime();
    $scope.messages.$add({title: $scope.title, body: $scope.msg, time: $scope.time });
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with data type. `time: 41010101` works well. But what wrong in `time: $scope.time` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.time is an object. Try this:

```
$scope.messages.$add({title: $scope.title, body: $scope.msg, time: $scope.time.valueOf()});
```